# Asio end socket functions: cancel, shutdown, close, release

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Which is the correct way to close and clean up a socket?

I have the io_service running in a secondary thread and I need to close the connection from the main thread:

```
void closeConnection()
{
    ioc.post([&socket]() {
        // Which ones do I have to call?
        // In what order?
        // What do they do?
        //socket.cancel();
        //socket.shutdown(asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
        //socket.close();
        //socket.release();
    });
    secondaryThread.join();
}
```

What is the difference between all these functions?

I've tried with this sequence ...

```
socket.cancel();
socket.close();
socket.release();
```

and seems to close up the connection without errors but takes too much time (about 5-10 seconds), so I guess I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: It turned out there was a silly mistake in my code. In the function that handles `read_async` I was posting another `read_async` even if the error code was `false`. Still think it would be interesting to have a clarification of what all these functions do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I presume you're talking about a *graceful close*, i.e. read/write any outstanding data, then close the socket.

The proper steps are:

1. Call `shutdown()` to indicate that you will not write any more data to the socket.
2. Continue to (async-) read from the socket until you get either an error or the connection is closed.
3. Now `close()` the socket (in the async read handler).

If you don't do this, you may end up closing the connection while the other side is still sending data. This will result in an ungraceful close.

---

`cancel()` and `release()` aren't the calls you use in a normal flow:

- `cancel()` cancels all outstanding asynchronous operations.
- `release()` releases ownership of the underlying native socket.

Comment: My application is a chat client, it is waiting for async read, wouldn't it get stuck in 2? I could cancel the async_read with `cancel()`? Thanks!

Comment: That's what `shutdown()` is for - it will cause any in-progress async read to finish with a "socket closed" error, at which point you can `close()` the socket.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly, `shutdown` does everything `cancel` does plus doesn't allow for future operations?

Comment: @tuket Not really. The `shutdown` function initiates the closure of the socket. Outstanding reads might complete if the other side sends you data. The `cancel` function cancels outstanding async operations, which leaves a mess. Say there's data in flight to you at the time -- if you cancel the outstanding async operations, how will you receive that data?

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks a lot!